# adding wizardPages dynamically and returning the result

Tags: java, swt, jface

I created a `Wizard`, then I created a `WizardPage` namely `FrontPage` and added it to wizard in wizard's `addPage` method.

Since I have only one page in `addPage` method, the Next button not shown. I want it to be shown.

In the `nextPressed` method of the `FrontPage`, I created an instance of another java class that the class runs the program written in another language. In several points of that program, I need to create wizardPage dynamically. For this purpose I created a java class to contribute to the program. This class namely `interfaceRule` create an instances of wizardPage in other plugin.

My questions is how can I add this wizardPages to the main wizard? And also how can I return the value that user select in wizardPage to `interfaceRule` class?

**edit:**

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
    boolean isNextPressed = "nextPressed".equalsIgnoreCase(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName());
    if (isNextPressed) {
        boolean validatedNextPress = this.nextPressed();
        if (!validatedNextPress) {
            return this;
        }
    }
    return super.getNextPage();
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to control the Next button in your class extending `Wizard`

You can call `setForcePreviousAndNextButtons(true)` in the wizard constructor to force the buttons always to be shown.

You can override the `needsPreviousAndNextButtons` method to decide if the buttons are required dynamically.

You can override the `getNextPage` method:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage(final IWizardPage page)
```

to control exactly which page is shown next (also `getPreviousPage`).

Comment: I don't understand how can I use and implement `getNextPage`. This method in the FrontPage already is the form of edit part of the post.

Comment: where should I override the `getNextPage`?

Comment: Everything I have described here is for a class extending `Wizard`.